# How to fix running a sql query in spring boot?

Tags: java, sql, spring

I am trying to run different SQL queries in my spring boot application, however when I use the code it produces an error where it can't compile. I am not sure if it is because of the way the query is setup, or because I just placed it into the wrong place. Please I have been researching how to properly place a SQL query in spring boot but have not found any information that would help me for the project I am working on.

**Repository:**

```
    package com.John.db;

    import java.util.List;



    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.John.model.AVSApplication;
    import com.John.model.AVSMapped;
    import com.John.model.ApplicationDTO;


    @Repository
    public interface AppRepository extends JpaRepository<AVSApplication, String>{


        @Query("SELECT new com.UPS.model.ApplicationDTO(d.appcode, d.acro, d.appname, e.mgpstatus) FROM AVSApplication d LEFT JOIN d.avsMapped e")
        List<ApplicationDTO> fetchEmpDeptDataLeftJoin();


        @Query("SELECT * FROM tier")
        List<String> getServerInfo();


    }
```

**Code Segment:**

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM tier")
            List<String> getServerInfo();
```

**Error:**

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'AVSController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mAppRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.UPS.db.AppRepository.getServerInfo()!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at com.UPS.TaddmDevApplication.main(TaddmDevApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.UPS.db.AppRepository.getServerInfo()!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.UPS.db.AppRepository.getServerInfo()!
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:566) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1050) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:561) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:254) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        ... 29 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT * FROM tier]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:729) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
        ... 58 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT * FROM tier]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:296) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
        ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the attribute that you want to get from the tier table, let us call it `name`, you might need to fix your query to select that attribute instead of *. For example:

```
SELECT t.name FROM tier t
```

Comment: N So the database name is taddm. The table name is tier. The column name is name. So would it be ```Select name.tier FROM taddm```?

Comment: No, it is should be `SELECT t.name FROM tier t`

Comment: Not sure where you got ```t``` from though?

Comment: Look at the error in the stack trace:`unexpected token: * near line 1`
This means that you cannot return * in the hibernate query, but the entity or the attributes that you need. Also note that `t`is used here as an alias for `tier`